# Onclick event not firing on jsfiddle.net

Tags: javascript, onclick, jsfiddle

I'm testing some javascript on jsfiddle and for some reason I can't get a function to fire on a button click. Any advice?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cronin/KTrEp/14/)

Comment: click the JsLint button and you will see coding errors

Comment: missing ) after argument list }); /_display/ (line 66, col 4)
You have js errors.

Comment: I would also suggest that you use a framework like Backbone.js.  You can create a 'Room' model and set its attributes - like price and room number.  Then push those models into a Collection  (sort of like a super-array that has some helpful methods).  You can use it with JQuery and it would really help clean up your code.

Answer (score 128):

In the `Frameworks & Extensions` panel, set `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`.

It took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: awesome! Can you explain what exactly this does? what does wrap mean with regards to onLoad()?

Comment: What is "Frameworks & Extensions" ?? i don't see that anywhere.

Comment: Click on the settings icon next to JAVASCRIPT in the JAVASCRIPT panel and choose 'no wrap - in <body>'

Answer (score 18):

You have configured JSFiddle to wrap the code in an onload event handler. Consequently the function you are trying to call `onclick` is out of scope.

Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Use jQuery's (since you are using jQuery already) [event binding](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) instead.

Comment: Although the above answer tells us how to fix the issue, I upvote yours because you explain what is going on :)