# HTML button onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

[image: 3 buttons 3 onclick events]

This might be a very basic question; believe me I found very hard to find the answer to this question on the internet. I have 3 HTML pages stored in my server (Tomcat locally) & i want to open these HTML pages on a button click. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Online Student Portal</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <form action="">
      <h2>Select Your Choice..</h2>
      <input type="button" value="Add Students">
      <input type="button" value="Add Courses">
      <input type="button" value="Student Payments">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.location` is the answer

Comment: Can you show us the html code for these buttons ?

Comment: You haven't found any examples of adding click handlers to HTML buttons? I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: Google `JavaScript on click window location`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Online Student Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<h2>Select Your Choice..</h2>

<input type="button" value="Add Students">
<input type="button" value="Add Courses">
<input type="button" value="Student Payments">

</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: As written, this would submit the form to an empty URL. But since the poster tagged this question with `Javascript`, @Rahul Tripathi's answer is appropriate, showing how to add Javascript click handlers to the button elements. A non-Javascript answer would require defining the form action; the posted button name would be submitted to the server there.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
    <title>Online Student Portal</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form action="">
         <input type="button" value="Add Students" onclick="window.location.href='Students.html';"/>
         <input type="button" value="Add Courses" onclick="window.location.href='Courses.html';"/>
         <input type="button" value="Student Payments" onclick="window.location.href='Payment.html';"/>
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: for UX purposes, these inputs should actually be links e.g. <a href="students.html">Add Students</a>

Answer (score 28):

You should all know this is inline scripting and is not a good practice at all...with that said you should definitively use javascript or jQuery for this type of thing:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head> 
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
    <title>Online Student Portal</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
    <form action="">
         <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Add"/>
    </form> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

JQuery

```
var button_my_button = "#myButton";
$(button_my_button).click(function(){
 window.location.href='Students.html';
});
```

Javascript

```
  //get a reference to the element
  var myBtn = document.getElementById('myButton');

  //add event listener
  myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    window.location.href='Students.html';
  });
```

See comments [why avoid inline scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254821/html-and-javascript-button-onclick-function) and also [why inline scripting is bad](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?#q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)

Answer (score 7):

on first button add the following.

```
onclick="window.location.href='Students.html';"
```

similarly do the rest 2 buttons.

```
<input type="button" value="Add Students" onclick="window.location.href='Students.html';"> 
<input type="button" value="Add Courses" onclick="window.location.href='Courses.html';"> 
<input type="button" value="Student Payments" onclick="window.location.href='Payments.html';">
```

Comment: thanks helped me! the <form> way doesn't seem to like IE8/SharePoint.

Comment: we can use location.href instead of window.location.href

Answer (score 2):

This example will help you:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')">
</form>
```

You can open next page on same page by:

```
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_self')">
```

Comment: Thanks Aman. But this code makes html open in seperate page. can i open it in same browser window

Answer (score 2):

Having trouble with a button onclick event in jsfiddle?

If so see [Onclick event not firing on jsfiddle.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114747/onclick-event-not-firing-on-jsfiddle-net)

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
"button" value="Add Students" onclick="window.location.href='Students.html';"> 
<input type="button" value="Add Courses" onclick="window.location.href='Courses.html';"> 
<input type="button" value="Student Payments" onclick="window.location.href='Payments.html';">
</body>
```

Comment: Could you explain some more about the code snippet and what details you've added and how they solve the problem. Add a reference to any relevant documentation/reading material if possible.