# Pass image source to <img> on button click event

Tags: javascript

I am getting user ID on fly and will use it to show the user image.
For that I want to set the `img` path when user click on button.
HEre is code:

HTML:

```
<img id="i1" style="display:none" src="" > </img>
<button typye="submit"  onclick="CallAfterLogin()"> Show image </button>
```

JS:

```
function CallAfterLogin() {
   var path = "http://thestylishdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/cute-dog2.jpg";
   document.getElementbyID(i1).src = path;
   document.getElementbyID(i1).display = "block";
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/qeyRK/2/

What's wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementbyID(i1).src = path;`

i1 isn't defined. Did you mean `"i1"`?

Comment: In addition to Carl's point, do you mean to use `getElementById`? Note: The last letter is a lower case 'd'.

Comment: @Steve: is JS case sensitive? Thanks for pointing! @ Card: yes I meant what you say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a syntactically correct version of your handler:

```
function CallAfterLogin() {
    var path = "http://thestylishdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/cute-dog2.jpg";

    var imgEl = document.getElementById("i1");

    imgEl.src = path;
    imgEl.style.display = "block";
}
```

However, the real trick here is with JSFiddle.  You have to look in Frameworks and Extensions and switch from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114747/onclick-event-not-firing-on-jsfiddle-net).

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PpbnG/2/

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

- replace document.getElementbyID(i1) with document.getElementById("i1")
- replace document.getElementbyID(i1).display with document.getElementById("i1").style.display

Full working function:

```
function CallAfterLogin() {
   var path = "http://thestylishdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/cute-dog2.jpg";
   document.getElementById("i1").src = path;
   document.getElementById("i1").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: essentially... i was just about to post this but i'll +1 instead

Answer (score 0):

```
function CallAfterLogin(){
        var path="http://thestylishdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/cute-dog2.jpg";
        document.getElementById("i1").src=path;
        document.getElementById("i1").style.display="block";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier if you just add onclick event to the button

```
onclick="document.getElementById('i1').style.display='block' "
```

just one line and job done. You can put the image path in the src with default display set to none, and when you click the image displays.

Comment: Image path coming in some function, so following my procedure is essential. Thanks for this answer.