# Program not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am programming a sudoku puzzle (http://www.jsfiddle.net/sZ7Aq/4/). It works okay on IE, but when I try it on Google Chrome, the button doesn't do anything when I click on it. Is there a way to fix it so it works on all browsers?

**Please note: I haven't finished it so there isn't a puzzle generating function. You must enter all numbers yourself.**

Here is my main() function (if you did not click on the link yet):

```
function main() {
    getcellVal();
    if (validate() == false) {
        alert("Something's not right!");
        return false;
    }
    alert("Good job!");
    return true;
}
```

My button:

```
<button onclick="javascript: main()">Check my answer</button>
```

Comment: use `<button onclick="main()">Check my answer</button>`, and read that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: I believe there is an issue with jsfiddle that you cannot use the onclick="main();" unless you perform a work around.

Comment: Check out this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114747/onclick-event-not-firing-on-jsfiddle-net

Comment: @Jonathan sorry typo `javascript: main()` not `javascript: main`. I changed it now.

Comment: @sam I have it on `localhost` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I found that there is an error in your other functions that is failing. Particularly "x0y0" is not defined.

Comment: looking through your fiddle, you are trying to access the input elements by their name directly. That is not possible.

Comment: sorry I mean `not javascript: main`

Comment: @sam it works on IE, though

Comment: I just put a form and set its name to `sudokuPuzzle`, and I referred to it like this: `sudokuPuzzle.x0y0.value`!

Comment: I now finished my sudoku and here it is: http://oliverni.com/sudoku/sudoku.html

Answer (score 0):

Use .addEventListener('click', main); For instance:

```
var check = document.getElementById('check');
check.addEventListener('click', main);
```

and of course add id="main" and remove the onclick from your button.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/sZ7Aq/3/)

Then open your console and fix the other bugs...

Answer (score 0):

From your jsfiddle, the error is in your getcellValue() function. This code is incorrect:

```
colVal  =  [[x0y0.value, x0y1.value, x0y2.value, x0y3.value, x0y4.value, x0y5.value, x0y6.value, x0y7.value, x0y8.value],
```

I would suggest you change your input elements to have an id attribute that matches the name. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="x0y0" id="x0y0">
```

Then change your getcellVal() function to use the getElementById function.

```
colVal  =  [[document.getElementById("x0y0").value, ...],
```

It will be much more verbose, but it will work in more browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Few things need to be corrected:

- Instead of defining an event such as `javascript: main()` inline, use unobtrusive solution to register the necessary event handlers programmatically.

Eg:

```
<button id="buttonid">Check my answer</button>

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('buttonid').onclick = main;
};
```

- You cannot access the DOM elements just by specifying their names. In your case `x0y0.value` will not return anything. Instead use `id` or `class` name to access the set of elements.

Eg:

```
<input type="text" name="x0y0" id="x0y0">
```

In javascript,

```
document.getElementById("x0y0").value
```

Comment: using <element>.onclick is not much better... using <element>.addEventListener('click', function) is much more accepted, as you can add more than one...