# Run function within object onclick

Tags: javascript, json, function, onclick

I want to run a function inside an object by `onclick`, but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

JSCode:

```
var jn = {
  alertText: function(){
    alert(arguments[0]);
  } 
};
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jn.alertText('hi')">[ClickHere]</a>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dotku/Nqh4S/2/

Comment: That's not valid JSON, but it is perfectly valid JavaScript: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LsCq/)

Comment: Works like a charm here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dff8/

Comment: OK but tell him that it works because JSFiddle isn't wrapping the JS in a "load" function, and so your methods are in the `window`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Onclick event not firing on jsfiddle.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114747/onclick-event-not-firing-on-jsfiddle-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the var statement and it will work. The `var` statement scopes it to that particular script file or tag, not the window object. DOM event handlers need to be scoped to something that's attached to the window object at some point.