# Javascript BMI Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Having trouble getting this to print anything in JSFiddle, although everything looks right to me. I'm unsure as to why HTML is not displaying the answer, but any help is welcome. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<h2>BMI Calculator</h2>
<p>
    Enter your weight in pounds:
    <input type="text" id="weight">
</p>

<p>
    Enter your height in inches:
    <input type="text" id="height">
</p>

<input type="button" onclick="bmiCalculator()" value="calculate">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function bmiCalculator() {
    var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
    var height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
    var finalWeight = weight * .45;
    var finalHeight = height * .025;

    var BMI = (finalWeight / Math.pow(finalHeight, 2));

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = BMI;
}
```

Comment: Always use the console/debug tools. It'll save you many head aches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code (you're missing a closing parenthesis in your BMI expression).
Here's the fixed code (I just added `)` right where it was needed) and it seems to me to be working fine.

```js
function bmiCalculator() {

  var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
  var height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
  var finalWeight = weight * .45;
  var finalHeight = height * .025;


var BMI = (finalWeight / Math.pow(finalHeight, 2));

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = BMI;

}
```

```html
<h2>
 BMI Calculator
</h2>

<p>
  Enter your weight in pounds:
  <input type="text" id="weight">
</p>

<p>
  Enter your height in inches:
   <input type="text" id="height">
</p>

<input type="button" onclick="bmiCalculator()" value="calculate">
  <p id="output" ></p>
```

**Note:** this code will not work on jsfiddle.net unless the Javascript option Load Type is set to `No wrap - in <body>`

I found that out thanks to this other stack: [Onclick event not firing on jsfiddle.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114747/onclick-event-not-firing-on-jsfiddle-net)

Comment: Interestingly enough, it works when I run it through this website, but when I try to run it on JSFiddle it doesn't seem to display the answer.

Comment: Indeed... Hadn't tried... I'm looking into it.

Comment: Haha! Got it! I will edit my answer to explain :)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much haha! I would've never guessed that, you're a godsend along with everyone else here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `)`

```
var BMI = (finalWeight / Math.pow(finalHeight, 2);
```

should be

```
var BMI = (finalWeight / Math.pow(finalHeight, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ')' in your code. Update you script with this

```
 function bmiCalculator() {

            var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
            var height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
            var finalWeight = weight * .45;
            var finalHeight = height * .025;


            var BMI = (finalWeight / Math.pow(finalHeight, 2));

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = BMI;

        }
```

Hope this will help :)